# Implementing weight normalization using TensorFlow layers' `kernel_constraint`

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

Some of the TensorFlow layers, such as [tf.layers.dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) and [tf.layers.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d), take in a `kernel_constraint` argument, which according to the [tf api docs docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d) implements an

> Optional projection function to be applied to the kernel after being updated by an Optimizer (e.g. used to implement norm constraints or value constraints for layer weights).

In [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07868), Salimans et al. present a neural network normalization technique, called weight normalization, which normalizes the *weight vectors* of the network layers, in contrast to, for example the batch normalization [[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167), which normalizes the actual data batch flowing through the layer. In some cases the computational overhead of the weight normalization method is lower and it can also be used in cases where the use of batch normalization is not feasible.

My question is: is it possible to implement the weight normalization using the abovementioned TensorFlow layers' `kernel_constraint`? Assuming `x` is an input with shape `(batch, height, width, channels)`, I thought I could implement it as follows:

```
x = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=x,
    filters=16,
    kernel_size=(3, 3),
    strides=(1, 1),
    kernel_constraint=lambda kernel: (
        tf.nn.l2_normalize(w, list(range(kernel.shape.ndims-1)))))
```

What would be a simple test case to validate/invalidate my solution?

[1] SALIMANS, Tim; KINGMA, Diederik P. Weight normalization: A simple reparameterization to accelerate training of deep neural networks. In: Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems. 2016. p. 901-909.

[2] IOFFE, Sergey; SZEGEDY, Christian. Batch normalization: Accelerating deep network training by reducing internal covariate shift. arXiv preprint arXiv:1502.03167, 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the title, the paper by Salimans and Kingma suggests to *decouple* the weight norm and their direction, rather than actually normalising the weights (i.e. setting their l2 norm to one as you suggested).

If you want to verify that your code has the intended effect even if it is not what they proposed, you can get the weights of the model and check their norm.
In pseudo-code:

```
model = tf.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
weights = model.get_weights()[i] # checking the weights of the i-th layer
flat_weights = weights.flatten()
import numpy as np
print(np.linalg.norm(flat_weights, 2))
```